# Rebinding to TFS after pc was renamed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Some as of yet unspecified domain error happened and my work computer had to be kicked off the domain, renamed, and added back. Now I can't seem to rebind my .net projects to our tfs repository. I've tried going to file/source control/change source control and rebinding, but that doesn't seem to fix anything. I thought I went in and updated my workspace name in tfs (or at least thought I did) and tried to rebind after that, then I started getting errors saying the file I was trying to check in wasn't in my workspace. I've seen several articles on unbinding/rebinding, but can't seem to find one that tells me how to rebind after my workspace name was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to delete the workspace. The computer name is a property on the workspace that can be changed without touching the files. Use tf.exe:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:OldComputerName /s:http://Tfs_server:8080
```

you can have a look at this post for more details:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2006/03/03/update-workspace.aspx

Comment: Is there a specific folder I need to be in? Computer keeps telling me it doesn't recognize 'tf' as an exe or bat.

Comment: OK OK OK, I think I got it. I was using the regular command prompt, not the Visual Studio command prompt. That looks like it sorted everything.